# Utilizing CDN for hosting images (or other media files) on the Firebase platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I am hosting a Firebase App and connected my custom domain to it, which was working smoothly. So my app is accessible at: https://example.com

Now, I want to serve the images, which are upload to the default Google Storage Bucket at a clean url (without access token) at: https://example.com/img/myimage.jpg. Futhermore, the images should be delivered via the CDN.
How can this be achived?

What I have figured out so far:

- I can make the bucket public and am able to access the image by this URL-pattern: https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucketname/myimage.jpg => The downside: No CDN and no custom domainname.
- I probably could setup another CDN in GCP, configure custom domain and point it to the bucket as described here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing The downside: I would prefer to use the exising CDN that Firebase is providing. Furthermore, the CDN from GCP seems to require an additional load-balancer, which is a bit of an overhead in terms of pricing.

I hope there is a simpler solution for solvig this common use case. Thx for support.

Comment: The only CDN that Firebase provides is Firebase Hosting.  But it's not integrated with Cloud Storage.  Consider instead just deploying all your files to Firebase Hosting to get the benefits of its CDN.  It'll be cheaper and faster than using Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. I guess I could sellect the "Pay-As-You-Go" Pricing model and serve my ~200GB of images, right? I still have questions: 1.) Will new deployments of the app remove the static content? Maybe I should create a separated hosting for serving the images? 2.)How can I copy the initial data there?